# Case statement invalid identifier

Tags: sql

I am in holiday mood now, just not able to get his straight end up with "invalid identifier". Does anyone see issues here

```
SELECT       DATE,   ACCOUNT,  SOURCE,
CASE WHEN   SOURCE ='0' THEN "CHICAGO"
      WHEN   SOURCE ='1' THEN "NEW YORK"
      WHEN   SOURCE ='T' THEN "SSCHICAGO"
      WHEN   SOURCE ='S' THEN "SSNEW YORK"
      ELSE "UAT" END AS TYPEACC
      FROM CUSTOMER

      WHERE       DATE BETWEEN '01 DEC 2015' AND ' 31 DEC 2015'
      GROUP BY
            DATE,   ACCOUNT,   SOURCE, TYPEACC
```

Comment: SQL strings should be enclosed in single quotes, not double quotes.

Comment: And you should use the default Date format `yyyy-mm-dd`

Comment: As juergen says, the [ISO 8601 date format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) is strongly recommended here. It will naturally sort correctly, plus is the internal format of most `DATE` fields. There's no such things as `BETWEEN` for dates in the format you've specified. `01 FEB 2015` comes *before* `01 JAN 2015`.

Comment: I have no issue specifying dates with the "format" or using "between". t is throwing an error on TYPEACC

Comment: I included single quotes this time and it still throws error as invalid identifier at TYPEACC

Comment: Replace the TYPEACC with the case statement

Comment: Thank you.SELECT       DATE,   ACCOUNT,  SOURCE,
CASE WHEN   SOURCE ='0' THEN 'CHICAGO'
      WHEN   SOURCE ='1' THEN 'NEW YORK'
      WHEN   SOURCE ='T' THEN 'SSCHICAGO'
      WHEN   SOURCE ='S' THEN 'SSNEW YORK'
      ELSE 'UAT' END AS TYPEACC
      FROM CUSTOMER

      WHERE       DATE BETWEEN '01 DEC 2015' AND ' 31 DEC 2015

Comment: SELECT DATE, ACCOUNT, SOURCE, CASE WHEN SOURCE ='0' THEN 'CHICAGO' WHEN SOURCE ='1' THEN 'NEW YORK' WHEN SOURCE ='T' THEN 'SSCHICAGO' WHEN SOURCE ='S' THEN 'SSNEW YORK' ELSE 'UAT' END AS TYPEACC FROM CUSTOMER WHERE DATE BETWEEN '01 DEC 2015' AND ' 31 DEC 2015

Comment: The above works. But does not work when I include group by with variable  TYPEACC or with complete case statement. What am I missing ?

Comment: In between I am using SQL DEVELOPER

Answer (score 0):

Here with proper formatting:

```
SELECT DATE,
       ACCOUNT,
       SOURCE, 
       CASE SOURCE
           WHEN '0' THEN 'CHICAGO' 
           WHEN '1' THEN 'NEW YORK' 
           WHEN 'T' THEN 'SSCHICAGO' 
           WHEN 'S' THEN 'SSNEW YORK' 
           ELSE 'UAT'
           END AS TYPEACC
FROM CUSTOMER 
WHERE DATE BETWEEN '2015-12-01' AND '2015-12-31'
GROUP BY DATE, 
      ACCOUNT,
      SOURCE, 
      CASE SOURCE
           WHEN '0' THEN 'CHICAGO' 
           WHEN '1' THEN 'NEW YORK' 
           WHEN 'T' THEN 'SSCHICAGO' 
           WHEN 'S' THEN 'SSNEW YORK' 
           ELSE 'UAT'
           END
```

You were also missing the single quote after the end date. I also fixed your date format for you. You don't code much, do you?